# How to write java script in vb.net code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net

Can anyone help me out as I need to write a Javascript in vb.net code?
what i meant is i am new to vb.net coding, I have a dynamically created table from a web-service, and for that table i need to add sorting function which is in the javascript code, i need to add this script to the dynamically created table
I tried with this:

```
     oSB.Append("table.RegisterStartupScript('SCRIPTNAME', '<script language='javascript'>function tname(){alert('kk')};</script>')")
```

but it seems to be not working atall.

Also i tried with this

```
     'oSB.Append("<script>$('[id^=tname] th').live('click',function(event){ alert('hello')}</script>")
```

my ajax function:

```
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Service1.asmx/GetRecipie",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

        data: "{'sDB':'" + sDB + "'}",
        dataType: "json",
        success: OnGetMemberSuccess,

        failure: function (errMsg) {
            $('#errorMessage').text(errMsg);  //errorMessage is id of the  div
        }

    });
    function OnGetMemberSuccess(data, status) {

        xistr = data.d.split(',');
        $("#MemberDetails").html(data.d);
        $('input[type=button]').attr('disabled', false);
    }

}
```

Table is created by this code(webservice):

```
     oSB.Append("<table id= '" + table_id + "' class='sortable' ><thead><tr><th class=border id='tname' >" + "Name" + "<img src='next.gif'/></th><th class=border>" + "Duration" + "</th><th class=border>" + "State" + "</th><th class=border>" + "Party" + "</th><th class=border>" + "Year" + "</th></tr></thead>")
     sNameValue = dr("sName").ToString
        sDurValue = dr("sDuration").ToString
        sStateValue = dr("sState").ToString
        sPartyValue = dr("sParty").ToString
        sYearValue = dr("sYear").ToString
        oSB.Append("<tbody id=tbodyid'>")
        ' oSB.Append("<tr id='trid'>")
        oSB.Append("<tr>")
        oSB.Append("<td id='tdid' class=border1>")
        oSB.Append(sNameValue)
        oSB.Append("</td>")

        oSB.Append("<td class=border1>")
        oSB.Append(sDurValue)
        oSB.Append("</td>")

        oSB.Append("<td id='td_state' class=border1>")
        oSB.Append(sStateValue)
        oSB.Append("</td>")

        oSB.Append("<td class=border1>")
        oSB.Append(sPartyValue)
        oSB.Append("</td>")

        oSB.Append("<td class=border1>")
        oSB.Append(sYearValue)
        oSB.Append("</td>")

        oSB.Append("</tr>")
        oSB.Append("</tbody>")
    End While
    dr.Close()
    con.Close()
    oSB.Append("</table>")
    'MsgBox(table.ToString)
    Debug.Print(oSB.ToString)
```

can somebody tell me where i am wrong?

Cheers again

Comment: please google search it?

Answer (score 2):

you can not write javascript directly in vb.net code. However you can register and fire javascript from vb.net code.

Try this

```
Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock("key","<script>alert('Hello World');</script>");
```

Try this vb code block:

```
Dim strScript As String = "<script>"
strScript += "alert('Hello, Pavan');"
strScript += "</script>"
Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock("strScript", strScript)
```

Comment: thanx jeev!!! Is this a vb.net code??? Its not working, i tried with that.

Comment: have a look here: http://roja-dotnet.blogspot.in/2011/10/calling-javascript-function-in-vb-net.html

Comment: also this:    http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/javascript/3/59770/calling-javascript-function-in-vb-net.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can not write javascript code in vb.net code. You can add/embed javascript code in vb.net code to execute on client. Usually you need to write javascript code in aspx page. You can use 
[ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb350750.aspx) to register the script from vb code.

Comment: i tried with these links, but doesnt seem to work     http://forums.asp.net/t/1382342.aspx and also     http://www.dotnetspider.com/forum/251475-How-write-java-script-vb.net-code.aspx

Comment: I answered your similar question yesterday did your try the solution?

Comment: I am not using a aspx page here, all i have is a html page which calls a webservice, and table is created in the webservice page dynamically, i do not want to use a aspx page atall.

Comment: How you call web service?

Comment: By javascript in HTML page using Ajax.

Comment: You need to return html from web service to ajax success function and assign the html to dom. You better add the ajax call in your question and expain what you want to do with html returned

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22430/discussion-between-pavan-and-adil)

Answer (score 1):

I can see that you're using

```
$('[id^=tname] th').live('click'...
```

From the jQuery docs however:

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to
>   attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use
>   .delegate() in preference to .live().
>   http://api.jquery.com/live/

In addition to that, TH is a really bad event target. As you'd need to click the TH, not the text within it. Otherwise your event won't trigger.

See the markup in here:
http://jsfiddle.net/4eXkT/2/

**That should work.**

In reality, you don't need to embed any javascript into your vb.net code. Simply include a javascript file into your page and use the jQuery's `.on()` event handler. If you must manage the javascript from your web service, have another endpoint for returning the javascript to be used in accordance to your web service generated code.

If you MUST use any other version than the latest jQuery, please refer to the documentation provided above.

Comment: Thanx for the reply,The code below worked for me.                                       $("[id^=tname]").live('click', function (event) {
        var s = event.target.id;
        alert('u hve clicked' + s);