# copy all photos from a webpage vb.net

Tags: vb.net, copy, clipboard

Hi hello i start to make a new application and i need to copy photos from a webpage to the clipboard with vb.net
I have try a few examples but i dint get it work.
well what i need is wen i go with right click of the mouse and i copy a photo from a webpage and insert in to a listbox.

with this code i can get all the page but i need only copy images how can i perform it on vb.net?

This is my code

```
 Private Sub Button2_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    WB.Document.ExecCommand("SelectAll", True, vbNull)
    WB.Document.ExecCommand("Copy", True, vbNull)
    Clipboard.GetImage()
End Sub
```

Comment: this would have to be done with javascript .   you can not have your Vb.Net code running off on some other server and performing the copy to clipboard function on the users local machine

Comment: I have found an example here at stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229071/how-to-write-java-script-in-vb-net-code that explain how to use the javascript on vb.net  here i can find a sample of javascript for that? Tanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i finally get it work so wen i copy with right click of the Mouse and then copy i get only one image
i get it work in a different way 
Like this

```
Private Sub Button2_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    'WB.Document.ExecCommand("SelectAll", True, vbNull)
    'WB.Document.ExecCommand("Copy", True, vbNull)
    Clipboard.GetImage()
    If My.Computer.Clipboard.ContainsImage Then
        PictureBox2.Image = My.Computer.Clipboard.GetImage
    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: The clipboard contains no standard way of containing multiple images, so you'd have to somehow make a custom object containing multiple images, and put that on the clipboard... using javascript. Personally I think it'd be easier to just download the html page in your program and get to the image urls that way, and just download them.